# Exception in UWP app on using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

When i try to use code as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-twin-getstarted in a UWP app, await Client.GetTwinAsync(); throws following exception.
I have tried on two different machine but same error, even calling OpenAsync results in same exception. I am trying to create UWP app so that I can deploy it on IOT device.

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.<>c.b__74_2(Task t)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at AzureIoTSuiteUWPDevice.MainPage.d__34.MoveNext()}
```

Comment: what build is running on your IoT device? And which version of the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client did you choose?

Comment: I have not deployed it to IOT device yet as I am still trying to get it working on my dev machine (Windows 10 1709.16299). 
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client  1.7.0
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared 1.5.0
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.0.8

Comment: Did you add some other packages in your solution?Please check if there is a package dependencies on System.Net.Security4.0.1. Actually,Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.7.0  dependencies on System.Net.Security4.3.2. Maybe there is some conflict in your solution.

Comment: No these are the only packages I have referenced in the project.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AntNN8UIo7AMragslpbUCqtiE0qloA) to simple solution for repro.

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded the solution you provided.The issue would be fixed by changing the Min Version of target to 16299 in solution properties. You can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version) to get how to choose a UWP version.

> **Minimum Version**. This sets the TargetPlatformMinVersion setting in your project file. It also determines the value of the TargetDeviceFamily@MinVersion attribute in your app package manifest. The value you choose specifies the minimum version of the UWP platform that your project can work with.

[image]

In addition, you should select *Private Networks(Client & Server)* in the [Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-capability)(Package.appxmanifest) to allow your app to access the IoT Hub.

> **privateNetworkClientServer**
>   On Windows, this provides access to a home or work network – the app can send information to or from your computer and other computers on the same network. On Windows Phone, provides the same access as internetClient or internetClientServer.

Comment: We are targeting build 14393 - is there a solution for such setup?

Comment: If your target is 14393, you can try to set the Target ersion and Min version as 14393.I don't have 14393 development environment and can not test with it, if you test with error,please feel free and let me know.

Comment: This is what I meant :) When I target 14393 I get the "System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1." error.

Comment: @michael-xu-msft My min and target versions are 14393 and the error is still happening. 

BTW. That error happens even if you deploy to 16299 (but your min version is 14393).

Comment: @tymtam, did you try with older version of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client when the target is 14393?

Comment: I've tried the prerelease ones and 1.7.0. Now you made me try an older version and it works, at least with 1.5.0. 

How to move forward with this? In the long term I would not want to rely on an old version of a critical library..

Comment: Hi,@tymtam, you can try to update the System.Net.Security to version 4.0.1.2 or higher via nuget(Install-Package System.Net.Security -Version Install-Package System.Net.Security -Version 4.3.2), because the latest Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client depends on this assembly.Or you can try to update .Net Framework to version 4.7.

Comment: I've tried having an explicit dependency on System.Net.Security, both 4.3.2 and 4.0.1 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Not being able to run Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client > 1.5.2 on 14393 seems like a big deal to me. Should I submit a ticket somewhere?

Comment: You can create an issue here(https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to downgrade the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client to Version 1.6.0 and everything worked fine.